# Write into database console after running it through shell script

Tags: bash, shell, automation, orientdb

I'm trying to write a script that will run the OrientDB shell and then connect via the proper command and credentials. However, I can't get any text to go in after running the console.

```
#!/bin/bash

(cd ../libs/orientdb-community-1.7.4/bin && source console.sh) && echo "CONNECT remote:localhost/pumpup root test"
```

This is what I get:

```
gsquare567@Macintosh ~/S/p/s/scripts> ./db_console.sh

OrientDB console v.1.7.4 (build UNKNOWN@r; 2014-06-23 19:29:10+0200) www.orientechnologies.com
Type 'help' to display all the commands supported.
Installing extensions for GREMLIN language v.2.5.0

orientdb>
```

After manually entering the command, it should do this:

```
orientdb> CONNECT remote:localhost/pumpup root test

Connecting to database [remote:localhost/pumpup] with user 'root'...OK
orientdb {pumpup}>
```

How can I get the `echo`ed command to run in the new console?

Answer (score 1):

With OrientDB 2.0-SNAPSHOT you can also enable echo:

```
(cd ../libs/orientdb-community-1.7.4/bin && source console.sh) && echo "set echo true;CONNECT remote:localhost/pumpup root test"
```

Comment: That opens the console but doesn't do anything else: `bash-3.2$ (cd ../libs/orientdb-current/bin && ./console.sh) && echo "set echo true;CONNECT remote:localhost/pumpup root test"

OrientDB console v.2.0-SNAPSHOT (build UNKNOWN@r; 2014-07-15 07:31:49-0400) www.orientechnologies.com
Type 'help' to display all the commands supported.
Installing extensions for GREMLIN language v.2.5.0

orientdb>`

Answer (score 0):

**Echo** prints string into standard output but not passes it to a command.

Console supports *file* name as an argument, so you can write your SQL script into a file and then run:

```
./console.sh script.sql
```